# Starting a shell at each boot

Tags: linux, systemd

I have NodeJS app. **app.js**. And I'm trying to start it at each boot of my linux device. For that here what I've tried :

**myshell.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT=/home/root/MYAPP/
RUNAS=root
start() {
    node /home/root/MYAPP/app.js
}

stop() {

}
```

placing this shell in /etc/init.d/  doesn't solve it. So my question is how may add my app.js as added startup service ?
thanks in advance!

Comment: The really easy option would be to start it with cron as a `@reboot` job. I wouldn't know how to do it with systemd though.

Comment: @Kusalananda  thanks for replying. if u have an example on how to do I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you could write your own systemd unit starting NodeJS based processes. THen again, you may want to look into NodeJS Processes Managers, such as PM2.

You'll find all you need registering a systemd service, then managing your NodeJS processes : https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/